# How do I manage an NSString as BOOL in iOS Core Data?

Tags: core-data, boolean, predicate

I have a webservice that returns a 0 string for a field I need called driveThru in order to determine whether a location has a drive thru service or not.

I take that "0" and store it as a string in my Core Data db just because its easier to store strings.

So I now want a view controller, with a BOOL property called self.driveThru which is set to true or false depending on whether the user tapped a cell or not, to create a predicate for the db fetch.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                                  predicateWithFormat:@"(driveThru == %@)",
                                  self.driveThru];
```

Do I need to convert that self.driveThru (BOOL) to a number or string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could just replace the type of that property as a `NSNumber`. This will be a more clear approach. Or you can just create your own map function that maps "0" or "1" strings to bools and vice versa.

If you follow the first, when you retrieve the string value from the server, just wrap it into a number like the following.

```
BOOL boolVal = [yourServerString boolValue];
NSNumber* numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:boolVal];
```

When you use it just grab the `boolValue` like this.

```
BOOL boolValue = [numberValue boolValue];
```

Your predicate will look like this.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"driveThru == %@",
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:[self driveThru]]];
```

Obviously, you could also think to subclass your entity and use scalar values for this.